# How would I read a line of user input with cin, split that line by white space, and store those tokens into an array of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, token, cin

Basically, yeah, everything as stated above. But I would like to do this without using the vector class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you use a different standard container?

Comment: standard container?
and yeah, I've gotten the aforementioned task done, but my previous implementation made use of the vector class, and I didn't find out until recently that I'm prohibited from using other than arrays.

Comment: I meant like `std::deque` and all the rest besides `std::vector`. I guess if it's just arrays, you can't.

Comment: [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) will help with the first part.  If you're not allowed to use any standard containers for the second part, then it's time to drop down to C and use things like `strtok` and `realloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Three steps:

1. Read a line using getline(). Make sure you use the free function, not the member of istream.
2. Determine the number of strings in the line. You could use a stringstream combined with istream_iterators and distance().
3. Allocate an array of sufficient size and copy the input elements. You could again use a stringstream with istream_iterators and copy().

Alternatively to steps 2 & 3, you could also dynamically enlarge your array or use a maximum size. Note that I'm intentionally not telling you how to do all this in order not to spoil you the learning experience. If you have concrete code, you are welcome to ask more specific questions though.